# How to apply a Value to a List of objects where the Value changes every 7 entries in the List?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a object, for the purposes of this example, it is quite simple:

```
public class DateEntry {
  public DateOnly Date { get; set; }
  public int WeekNumber { get; set; }
}
```

I get back a `List` of 42 instances of the `DateEntry` object.

The `Date` field gets filled in automatically.  What I need to do, is for each 7 of these objects, I need to increment the `WeekNumber` by 1. This is not the `WeekOfYear` it is just a requirement by our UI that the first week is 1, second week is 2 all the way to 6 (just like the weeks shown in a single month of any calendar.)

I know I can do this `for` loops, but would like to do it with `LINQ.`

I have a similar method that would break it into a list of lists, each inner list having 7 entries in it. But I really want to just modify the original list and have the `WeekNumber` reflect which of the 6 weeks it is in. I just could not wrap my head around how to alter the following method.

```
public static List<WeekOfDateEntries> SplitIntoWeeks(this List<DateEntry>? source)
{
  var weekIndex = 1;

  if (source is null || source.Count == 0)
    return [];

  return source
    .Select((x, i) => new { Index = i, Value = x })
    .GroupBy(x => x.Index / 7)
    .Select(x => new WeekOfDateEntries
    {
      WeekNumber = weekIndex++,
      Dates = x.Select(v => v.Date).ToList()
    })
    .ToList();
}
```

### Answer

With a minor tweak, @harald-coppoolse answer was correct. I just had to swap the `index` position.

```
return source
  .Select((dateEntry, index) => new TimeEntryRecord
  {
     Date = dateEntry.Date,
     WeekNumber = index / 7 + 1,
   })
  .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually jotting down your requirements will help you with your LINQ statements.

### Requirement

**Input:** an enumerable sequence of DateEntries.

**Output** a sequence of DateEntries with the same length, with the same values of property Date, in the same order, but with a value of property WeekNumber according to the following defintion:

> WeekNumber of DateEntry[i] in the input sequence == i/7 + 1

So DateEntry[0] to DateEntry[6] will have WeekNumber 1; DateEntry[7] to DateEntry[13] will have WeekNumber 2, etc.

How about this:

```
IEnumerable<DateEntry> inputDateEntries = ...
IEnumerable<DateEntry> outputDateEntries = inputDateEntries
    .Select( (index, dateEntry) => new DateEntry
        {
            Date = DateEntry.Date,
            WeekNumber = index / 7 + 1,
        });
```

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick. Granted, there was an issue as the `index` parameter is the 2nd one, not the first. I have altered my post to include your answer there (with the index tweak.)

Answer (score 1):

No need to increment the local variable which should be avoided anyway.

The [`Group.Key`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.igrouping-2.key?view=net-8.0) is all you need:

```
return source
    .Select((x, i) => new { Index = i, Value = x })
    .GroupBy(x => x.Index / 7)
    .Select(x => new WeekOfDateEntries
    {
      WeekNumber = x.Key + 1,
      Dates = x.Select(v => v.Date).ToList()
    })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! However, this answer uses the old `WeekOfDateEntries` that I am not wanting to use.